# How to deactivate the user automatically after 90 days if he had no purchase with in 90 days

Tags: magento-1.7, php, customer, database

How to deactivate or inactive the user automatically after 90 days if he had no purchase with in 90 days.
in our website

Comment: You could at this module from Vinai Kopp http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-activation.html,  then extend on the functionality. You could add a cron that would de-activate the customers after they have been in-active for 90 days

Comment: @brentwpeterson this looks like an answer to me

Comment: @brentwpeterson You would have posted it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write custom module to handle this task. Following logic you can use: when customer logged in, your observer tracks login time and save this time to **last_activated** attribute of customer. Before this you should check if difference between current time and last_activated time less or nor to particular period which is given in your configuration, see implemention:
/app/code/community/SSD/CustomerActivation/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <SSD_CustomerActivation>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </SSD_CustomerActivation>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <customer_customer_authenticated>
                <observers>
                    <ssd_customeractivation>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>SSD_CustomerActivation_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>customerCustomerAuthenticated</method>
                    </ssd_customeractivation>
                </observers>
            </customer_customer_authenticated>
        </events>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <models>
            <ssd_customeractivation>
                <class>SSD_CustomerActivation_Model</class>
            </ssd_customeractivation>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <ssd_customeractivation_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>SSD_CustomerActivation</module>
                </setup>
            </ssd_customeractivation_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

/app/code/community/SSD/CustomerActivation/etc/system.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <customer translate="label" module="customer">
            <groups>
                <expiration translate="label">
                    <label>Account expiration</label>
                    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <enabled>
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </enabled>
                        <period>
                            <label>Expiration Period</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <validate>validate-number</validate>
                            <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                            <comment>Account expiration period with hours</comment>
                            <depends>
                                <enabled>1</enabled>
                            </depends>
                        </period>
                    </fields>
                </expiration>
            </groups>
        </customer>
    </sections>
</config>
```

/app/code/community/SSD/CustomerActivation/sql/ssd_customeractivation_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php:

```
<?php
/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();
$setup         = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$attributeCode = 'last_activated';
$setup->addAttribute('customer', $attributeCode, array(
    'label'        => 'Last Activated',
    'type'         => 'int',
    'input'        => 'text',
    'visible'      => true,
    'required'     => false,
    'position'     => 130,
));
$installer->endSetup();
```

/app/code/community/SSD/CustomerActivation/Model/Observer.php:

```
<?php
class  SSD_CustomerActivation_Model_Observer
{
    public function customerCustomerAuthenticated($observer)
    {
        /**
         * @var $customer Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
         */
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getModel();
        if (Mage::getStoreConfig('customer/expiration/enabled')) {
            $period        = intval(Mage::getStoreConfig('customer/expiration/period'));
            $lastActivated = $customer->getLastActivated();
            $now           = time();
            if ($period * 3600 < $now - $lastActivated) {
                Mage::throwException('Customer account expired.');
            }
            $customer->setLastActivated(time())->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Look at this module from Vinai Kopp magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-activation.html, then extend on the functionality by adding a cron that would de-activate the customers after they have been in-active for 90 days.